# find a date when sales for id reach some level

Tags: sql

I need to find the date, when the sum paid by every user exceeded $100. I have a table in below format:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------+----+
|     pay_date, user_id, transaction_sum |            |    |
+----------------------------------------+------------+----+
|     01/01/14, A1,      $2              |            |    |
|     01/01/14, A2,      $5              |            |    |
|     01/01/14, B1,      $10             |            |    |
|     03/01/14, A1,      $2              |            |    |
|     03/01/14, B1,      $2              |            |    |
|     03/01/14, C1,      $5              |            |    |
|     04/01/14, A3,      $2              |            |    |
|     04/01/14, A3,      $20             |            |    |
|     04/01/14, C1,      $5              |            |    |
+----------------------------------------+------------+----+
    ...

(ordered by pay_date)
```

I'd like to have in result the table like this:

```
user_id, pay_date
A1,      03/03/14
A2,      30/03/14
A3,      22/05/14
B1,      01/01/15
C1,      12/10/14
```

the total cumulative amount of money paid by some users will exceed $100, but I need the date when it was exceeded. For other users it will not exceed, I don't need them in the table.

Apologies if I haven't explained this clearly enough
Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Date/time functions are too often product specific.)

Comment: What have you done so far by yourself? Any efforts?

Comment: @jarlh TransactSQL if I correctly understood your question (Amazon Redshift)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev this is actually a part of some work I'm stuck on, the work is to know how long it takes for user to spend $100 (for those who spend >=$100), I know how to do the rest, but that part is unfamiliar to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Redshift supports Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(pay_date)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT pay_date, user_id,
      SUM(transaction_sum) -- cumulative sum based on pay_date
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
            ORDER BY pay_date
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cum_sum
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
WHERE cum_sum > 100 -- only rows where cumulative sum exceeds limit 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is very elegant solution! I regret my reputation is not letting me vote it up

Answer (score 0):

What your example is, isn't exactly as your question asks.

If you want your example then you can simply do

```
select user_id, pay_date from TABLE where transaction_sum > 100;
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, dnoeth gave a very useful advise for the case